# Solutions to an interesting diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory

Find all solutions to $4y^2+3 = w^2z^2 + 3(w^2+z^2)$ in positive integers.

I am more curious about the actual process of finding the solutions rather than the solutions themselves as I am actually working on a more general case of the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of integer solutions. In fact, for each integer value of $w$, I believe that there's an infinite family of solutions described by the corresponding Pell's equation. So, you might want to further clarify what you're going for.

Comment: Good point. I just realized this. This equation is basically a simplified version of the equation (x^2+3)(y^2+3) = (w^2+3)(z^2+3) where x =1. I'm trying to think of a way to use this to solve a harder question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4y^2+3 = (w^2+3)z^2+3w^2\tag{1}$$

According to Mordell' book Diophantine equation, given one integer solution $(x_0,y_0)$ of equation $(1)$,
there exists an infinitely many integer solutions if $D=16(w^2+3)>0$ and $\varDelta=16(w^2+3)(3w^2-3) \ne 0.$

Hence let assume $w \ne 1.$

Since an equation $(1)$ has a solution $(y,z)=(w,1)$, then equation $(1)$ has an infinitely many integer solutions.

For instance, let $w=2.$

$4y^2-7z^2 = 9$
Recursive solutions are given as follows.
$y_0=2$
$z_0=1$

$y_{n+1} = 127y_n + 168z_n$
$z_{n+1} = 96y_n + 127z_n$

Comment: Ah! I didn't realized that $(w, 1)$ was a seed solution.